# Netbeans does not log with log4j

Tags: java, logging, netbeans, log4j

I am currently working on a java application that uses log4j for its default logging. Recently however Netbeans has stopped doing any logging that goes through log4j at all.

I know that log4j is properly configured, as the same project logs perfectly fine in Eclipse, and even calling the .jar as built by Netbeans logs without issue!

This behavior is identical on different machines, too.

I have already spent a good amount of time searching for a possible cause, perhaps a setting that suppresses logging in the project preferences, but I'm stumped.

Does anyone have an idea what could be causing this strange behavior?

EDIT: I have tried adding simple log4j logging to a new project simply to check and it works just fine there. Can anyone point out potential causes in Netbeans' project settings then?

EDIT2: It looks like Netbeans was reading the properties file of a dependency rather than the one I placed in the source folder. After manually forcing log4j to use the one in src it works.

Comment: Where you place the log4j.properties file in your project?

Comment: @Sivakumar I placed it in the main source folder as set in classpath. However, I have found the root of the problem and amended the question accordingly